# Getting loop value outside the loop MVC C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a loop and assigning the value outside the loop in an html actionlink. But every time when I am submitting the link, only getting the last value into the actionlink. Could someone help me how can I get all values from the loop. My expected result is when conditions met, it will assign actionlinks class name - visited, if not - NotVisited. I have many actionlinks in the view page.

My code is –

```
string[] class_name = null;

    @foreach (string items in str_array) 
                            // str_array I am getting like [0] = 1
                            //                             [1] = 2 
        {
            if (items.ToString() == class_id.ToString()) 
            // class id is integer value eg. 1 and getting from db
            {
                class_name = new string[] { "visited" };  
            }
            else
            {
                class_name = new string[] { "NotVisited" };   
            }
        }

    @Html.ActionLink("test", "R_Class", "R_Class", null, new { @class = string.Format("{0}", class_name), onclick = "return false;" })
```

Comment: When you coming out  the loop last generated string array object is reffered by the reference variable class_name .

Comment: @Imad, I want when condition met, it will assign the value to the class into the actionlink

Comment: @class_name, exactly I am getting right now what you said, but I want not only the last one, all of them when condition met

Comment: But how can you apply both classes if both conditions are met. It will break your design.

Comment: @arifpervez - After the view is generated and sent to the client, the variable no longer exists. The only way to change the class on the client is to use JavaScript.

Comment: Why is `_class_name` an array? What is `class_id`? Explain what your trying to do.

Comment: Is there any other way I can achieve this

Comment: @arifpervez you want to apply classes multiple times?

Comment: @StephenMuecke, class_id is a List of array, for this reason I thought, it will be good to use class_name as an array of string not a string

Comment: @Imad, yes I want to apply classes multiple times

Comment: @arifpervez, You need to edit you question and explain what your trying to do, what the values of your variables and what the expected result is

Comment: @StephenMuecke, my variables value str_array (like [0] = 1, [1] = 2) already mentioned in the question, the expected result is when condition meet [items.ToString() (eg. 1) == class_id.ToString()], I need the action link class name - visited.

Comment: Edit your question! (and what is `class_id` and what is the expected result)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague but I'm assuming you want to assign the first visited class found (if any)

```
    var class_name = new string[] {}; // I changed this line just to comply with coding best practices

    @foreach (string items in str_array) 
                            // str_array I am getting like [0] = 1
                            //                             [1] = 2 
        {
            if (items.ToString() == class_id.ToString())
            {
                class_name = new string[] { "visited" };
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                class_name = new string[] { "NotVisited" };   
            }
        }

    @Html.ActionLink("test", "R_Class", "R_Class", null, new { @class = string.Format("{0}", class_name), onclick = "return false;" })
```

If my assumption is true and if when the class is not 'visited' it's supposed to be 'NotVisited' then you can have a less verbose code like this:

```
    var class_name = new string[] { "NotVisited" }; 
    @foreach (string items in str_array) 
        {
            if (items.ToString() == class_id.ToString())
            {
                class_name = new string[] { "visited" };
                break;
            }
        }

    @Html.ActionLink("test", "R_Class", "R_Class", null, new { @class = string.Format("{0}", class_name), onclick = "return false;" })
```

Comment: many thanks, this is exactly I was looking for, thanks for your help

Comment: You're welcome mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you want to do this but looks like you want to apply classes multiple times.

```
string[] class_name = null;
@foreach (string items in str_array) 
{
    if (items.ToString() == class_id.ToString())
    {
        class_name += " visited";  
    }
    else
    {
        class_name += " NotVisited"   
     }
}

@Html.ActionLink("test", "R_Class", "R_Class", null, new { @class = string.Format("{0}", class_name), onclick = "return false;" })
```

Comment: Sorry, I am getting conversion error

Comment: Still I am getting same conversion error

Comment: Hi Imad, Many thanks for your assistance, I am getting cannot convert type error, but the other answer is working. Many many thanks